# Rewrite a sequence of assignments with the apply functions in R

Tags: r, loops, apply

I was trying to simulate a sequence of measures of heights and weights of horses by breed, sampling the data from a list of breeds of horses available in the UK. I ended up using a very long code made of lots of copy-paste and I think there must be a more efficient way to do this, but I tried with the `apply` functions, but I was unsuccessful.

The MWE is the following

```
library(tidyverse)

horses_meas <- tribble(
    ~breed, ~mean_h, ~sd_h, ~mean_w, ~sd_w,
    "Hannover", 1.69, 0.10, 600, 25,
    "Arabian", 1.50, 0.05, 400, 45,
    "Holsteiner", 1.68, 0.05, 575, 125
)

# Simulation by breed
type_1 <- bind_cols(breed = rep(horses_meas$breed[1], 20), 
                    weight = rnorm(20, horses_meas$mean_w[1], horses_meas$sd_w[1]),
                    height = rnorm(20, horses_meas$mean_h[1], horses_meas$sd_h[1]))
type_2 <- bind_cols(breed = rep(horses_meas$breed[2], 20), 
                    weight = rnorm(20, horses_meas$mean_w[2], horses_meas$sd_w[2]),
                    height = rnorm(20, horses_meas$mean_h[2], horses_meas$sd_h[2]))
type_3 <- bind_cols(breed = rep(horses_meas$breed[3], 20), 
                    weight = rnorm(20, horses_meas$mean_w[3], horses_meas$sd_w[3]),
                    height = rnorm(20, horses_meas$mean_h[3], horses_meas$sd_h[3]))

horses <- bind_rows(type_1, type_2, type_3)

print(horses)
```

Can you please help me transforming this into a more effective piece of code? I would like to be able to select a different number of horses (the ones in the MWE are just the outcome of a random sampling, but ideally this number may vary), and I don't want every time to cut and paste all the `type_i` assignments.

I reckon that something like assigning a temporary variable `x <- NULL` and then creating a list `x['breed']` to fill in with `for` could help, but I would like to do this with the `apply` functions or using the `tidyverse` instead.

Thank you for any help you may give me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One `tidyverse` approach would be to use `purrr::pmap` to loop over the rows of `horses_meas` like so:

```r
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(123)

purrr::pmap(horses_meas,
  function(breed, mean_w, sd_w, mean_h, sd_h, n) {
    data.frame(
      breed = breed,
      weight = rnorm(n, mean_w, sd_w),
      height = rnorm(n, mean_h, sd_h)
    )
  },
  n = 5
) |>
  bind_rows()
#>         breed   weight   height
#> 1    Hannover 585.9881 1.861506
#> 2    Hannover 594.2456 1.736092
#> 3    Hannover 638.9677 1.563494
#> 4    Hannover 601.7627 1.621315
#> 5    Hannover 603.2322 1.645434
#> 6     Arabian 455.0837 1.589346
#> 7     Arabian 416.1916 1.524893
#> 8     Arabian 418.0347 1.401669
#> 9     Arabian 404.9807 1.535068
#> 10    Arabian 374.9871 1.476360
#> 11 Holsteiner 441.5220 1.595665
#> 12 Holsteiner 547.7531 1.721889
#> 13 Holsteiner 446.7494 1.687669
#> 14 Holsteiner 483.8886 1.623093
#> 15 Holsteiner 496.8701 1.742691
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I have eventually used a slight modification of this answer: I am not quite sure why you haven't used `tibble` rather than `data.frame` in the function, but this is a really nice idea, and I have found clever to loop over the rows of the dataframe.

Comment: Can I ask you, if you know, why the names on the function must be the same as the names of the columns? If I use `function (a, b, c, d, e)` it gives me error, but if I use `~data.frame` and then the positions `..1` to `..5` it works perfectly. I am a bit puzzled by this, as the documentation of `pmap` say I could use a function, but it doesn't say with matching variables as the variables in the data.

Comment: In case of a data frame (or more general a named list) the column names are used as argument names. Hence you will get an error `unused arguments ...` when using different argument names for your function. This said, one option would be to get rid of the "column names" (in general this will give an error for a tibble but here it works), i.e. try `purrr::pmap(unname(horses_meas), function(a, b, c, d, e) { ... })`.

Answer (score 1):

I would just map everything out all at once.

```r
library(tidyverse)

horses_meas <- tribble(
    ~breed, ~mean_h, ~sd_h, ~mean_w, ~sd_w,
    "Hannover", 1.69, 0.10, 600, 25,
    "Arabian", 1.50, 0.05, 400, 45,
    "Holsteiner", 1.68, 0.05, 575, 125
)


map_dfr(
  1:nrow(horses_meas),
  ~with(
      horses_meas,
      tibble(
        breed = rep(breed[.x], 20),
        weight = rnorm(20, mean_w[.x], sd_w[.x]),
        height = rnorm(20, mean_h[.x], sd_h[.x])
      )
    )
)
#> # A tibble: 60 x 3
#>    breed    weight height
#>    <chr>     <dbl>  <dbl>
#>  1 Hannover   611.   1.73
#>  2 Hannover   641.   1.61
#>  3 Hannover   575.   1.52
#>  4 Hannover   624.   1.68
#>  5 Hannover   610.   1.80
#>  6 Hannover   552.   1.72
#>  7 Hannover   606.   1.63
#>  8 Hannover   601.   1.86
#>  9 Hannover   591.   1.61
#> 10 Hannover   593.   1.80
#> # i 50 more rows
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I like your idea very much, but I eventually gave the tick to the other answer, because I have found very clever to loop over the rows of the `horses_meas` dataframe. However, this would have been my second choice.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use rowwise operations and nested data:

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(tidyr)

horses_meas <- tribble(
  ~breed, ~mean_h, ~sd_h, ~mean_w, ~sd_w,
  "Hannover", 1.69, 0.10, 600, 25,
  "Arabian", 1.50, 0.05, 400, 45,
  "Holsteiner", 1.68, 0.05, 575, 125
)

horses_meas %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(sim = tibble(weight = rnorm(20, mean_w, sd_w),
                      height = rnorm(20, mean_h, sd_h)) %>% list()) %>% 
  unnest(sim) %>% 
  select(!contains("_"))
#> # A tibble: 60 × 3
#>    breed    weight height
#>    <chr>     <dbl>  <dbl>
#>  1 Hannover   611.   1.58
#>  2 Hannover   590.   1.59
#>  3 Hannover   575.   1.55
#>  4 Hannover   612.   1.58
#>  5 Hannover   596.   1.76
#>  6 Hannover   600.   1.71
#>  7 Hannover   641.   1.77
#>  8 Hannover   613.   1.67
#>  9 Hannover   617.   1.60
#> 10 Hannover   612.   1.72
#> # ℹ 50 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for that. I am not familiar with `rowwise`, hence why I have ticked a different answer using the `purrr` package. However, this answer is also interesting and gives me material to work on. Thank you for that.